# reading CSV data as Dictionaries and save again in another CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, parsing, dictionary

data in my csv has two column sha and commit

```
sha commit
a06d16359ca3b529aea42ca4d84f9a4fc99de0dd {'author': {'name': 'Katrina Owen', 'email': 'kytrinyx@github.com', 'date': '2018-03-09T15:08:39Z'}, 'committer': {'name': 'GitHub', 'email': 'noreply@github.com', 'date': '2018-03-09T15:08:39Z'}, 'message': 'Merge pull request #989 from europ/doc_fix\n\nCommand example fix in documentation.', 'tree': {'sha': 'd472f9d110f0f3c766c23902e7dc466ad9cb101a', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/trees/d472f9d110f0f3c766c23902e7dc466ad9cb101a'}, 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/commits/a06d16359ca3b529aea42ca4d84f9a4fc99de0dd', 'comment_count': 0, 'verification': {'verified': True, 'reason': 'valid', 'signature': '-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----\n\nwsBcBAABCAAQBQJaoqN3CRBK7hj4Ov3rIwAAdHIIAF7dma2a+9suqB/dUTZl23hP\nvYmfUSpt+62r0Kwi8HIHrxy9yHgiTQ6VqwvOeTsbNzDhVlqD6wcB4V3Eyyhq4j9K\nu7r3OtKdRD4FFqZDjMnUgKSAADFssFKM6txG0+l4+jtoP+KdBqSb6X/5F+iBTrCw\nROjDly/EAv9FGoxzhrPPlm46Q2GWQ3dGPH4KZpvhZRiLuZsESbjXhIzRR/QqmlrF\n/gKmPhg59rsYOkymGF4MpEQs4U9PNYTfv9F6hdRGaTj4utQXz3Bojuet+qZhWYfp\ntAhi2Q/Mp7TKHsGAWv5yZ3HHdKPSDFYO7jhkWFbQ106UTJUXnBHlSdN0HtfEJ/I=\n=8CFd\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----\n', 'payload': 'tree d472f9d110f0f3c766c23902e7dc466ad9cb101a\nparent 86362b9ea392bb88a9041a7d31b58e779ba8459b\nparent 08b226ea40f15547195338827bb277686385b944\nauthor Katrina Owen <kytrinyx@github.com> 1520608119 -0700\ncommitter GitHub <noreply@github.com> 1520608119 -0700\n\nMerge pull request #989 from europ/doc_fix\n\nCommand example fix in documentation.'}}
```

I need the data from commit commit column like author[name], commiter[name]
Any idea how can I parse it after reading data from csv file?

here is code

```
commit_link = Request(commit_urls,headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}) 
        response = urlopen(commit_link) 
        commit_json = response.read().decode("utf-8")
        commit_data = json.loads(commit_json)
        # open a file for writing
        commit_file = open('raw_commit_data.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
        # create the csv writer object
        csvwriter = csv.writer(commit_file)
        count = 0
        for commit in commit_data:
            if count == 0:
                header = commit.keys()
                csvwriter.writerow(header)
                count += 1
            csvwriter.writerow(commit.values())
        commit_file.close()
```

Comment: What delimiter is your CSV using? Spaces or commas won't work here. Also how did you *get* this data? Can you not parse before you generated this file?

Comment: i think its ":"

Comment: No... That is a key separator in the JSON. What is the character before the `{'author'`?

Comment: I parse github public repsitorires data and it give me 8 keys values and have nested dictionaries like above im just showing first two column

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of all your code, please?

Comment: here is link that I parse https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/discussions/commits

Comment: I added my code now check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually *parse the JSON*, not try to manipulate the file after the fact.

```
commit_data = json.loads(commit_json)
# open a file for writing
header = ['sha', 'author', 'committer']
with open('raw_commit_data.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as commit_file:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(commit_file)
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    for commit in commit_data:
        # Parse the objects
        sha = commit['sha']
        author = commit['author']['name']
        committer = commit['committer']['name']

        csvwriter.writerow([sha, author, committer])
```

Comment: Yes, not all committers or authors have names. This is only an example of what you should do. It's not error proof